# Autodesk Viewer3D Third Party library, can I make it work with LWC?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, locker-service, third-party

I'm trying to create an Autodesk 3D Viewer inside Salesforce using LWC.
**I have replicated the same code inside a VisualForce Page and it works perfectly.**

Reading the documentation I have to load this Javascript Library inside LWC:

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js
```

I follow the steps uploading the library to Salesforce as a static resource and calling the loadScript function.

However the 3D Viewer still not working and loading the library returns some errors. The JS library uses "workers" so I guess something is messing up with the Locker service in Salesforce. I have LWS enabled too.

My question then is, **can I make this work with LWC at all? Why is LWC so locked compared with VFP?**

Thanks.

Comment: You'll want to read up on [Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/security-lwsec-intro.html) which is replacing Locker Service.